# how to do Merged localhost and 127.0.0.1 in ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, merge, localhost

I cant see my project on ubuntu by `http://127.0.0.1`, but i can see it by `http://localhost`.
How to merged localhost and 127.0.0.1 in ubuntu ?

AND I Set `127.0.0.1 localhost` in hosts but still Dose not work

Answer (score 0):

Your hostfile (/etc/hosts) should have an entry that looks like this on the first line:

127.0.0.1     localhost

I would make sure those entries are present.

Comment: we have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in (/etc/hosts)